# Cómo copiar un directorio desde ASM al filesystem?

Tags: oracle, shell

Alguien sabe si desde ASM, se puede copiar un directorio completo hacia un filesystem (en la misma maquina) No encuentro un comando para eso, y la forma que tengo para hacerlo ahora es iterando los elementos en un ciclo for.

actualizacion: agrego el codigo del script como lo estoy haciendo hasta ahora

```
#Bajar respaldo de ASM a filesystem 
. $HOME/.bash_profile
DirBkpActual=`date +"%Y_%m_%d"`
DIA=`date +%Y%m%d`
rm -f /tmp/*_TAG*.*

#esto no funciona, el comando cp no es capaz de copiar un directorio
#asmcmd cp +DATA/$1/BACKUPSET/"$DirBkpActual" /media/backupdb/rman/"$1"/"$DIA"

#esto si funciona, copia los archivos desde el asm al filesystem /tmp mediante un ciclo
for i in $(asmcmd ls +DATA/$1/BACKUPSET/"$DirBkpActual"); do
   asmcmd cp +DATA/$1/BACKUPSET/"$DirBkpActual"/$i /tmp/"$DirBkpActual"
   asmcmd rm +DATA/$1/BACKUPSET/"$DirBkpActual"/$i 
done
```

Saludos y gracias por leer

Comment: Por favor, añade el código relevante a como lo estás haciendo ahora.

Comment: hola. actualice y puse el codigo de cmo esta funcionando ahora

Comment: No conozco los detalles de asmcmd, pero, por lo que dice la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e18951/asm_util003.htm#OSTMG94462), no me haría muchas ilusiones.